# Every provably recursive function in PA is bounded by a Hardy function

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion, proof-theory, peano-axioms

The following lemma and proof are from Takeuti's Proof Theory (2nd edition, pp. 126-127), I've highlighted the problematic part in blue:

[image: Takeuti Lemma 12.34]

How does Takeuti get this inequality? If the proof $x$ is not reducible then $r(x) = x$ and also $|x| = |r(x)|$, but to apply the induction hypothesis we need $|r(x)| < |x|$.

It would also be very beneficial to me if someone could explain the role that $u(x)$ is supposed to play in this proof.

Comment: Definition 12.26 is the definition of $c.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, I looked two pages back and there was nothing, I missed this (I read that part some time ago). Still... any reasonable textbook should make a reference there... I find myself increasingly frustrated with this sloppiness. It cost me two hours for nothing :/

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your comment.